# Is it possible to compose quick "Add Education" button to LinkedIn like you can with licenses and certifications?

Tags: http, linkedin-api, getparameter

I know that you can compose an html link, which you can send via email or attach to your web site to quickly add licenses and certifications information to user's LinkedIn Profile, which is often used by sites like Coursera, etc.

[LinkedIn even has guide for this.](https://addtoprofile.linkedin.com/)

And here's how the link looks like:

`<div><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/add?startTask=CERTIFICATION_NAME&name=Test%20Certificate&organizationId=1337&issueYear=2018 &issueMonth=2&expirationYear=2020&expirationMonth=5&certUrl= https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flearn%2Fcertifications%2Fd365-functional-consultant-sales&certId=1234"><img src="https://download.linkedin.com/desktop/add2profile/buttons/en_US.png " alt="LinkedIn Add to Profile button"></a></div>`

Here you can use GET parameters to automatically fill in the form for the user, so they can just press the "Add to profile button".

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to do similar thing, but to quickly add information about education. Basically, my university is trying to send emails to graduates, so they can add their diploma to their LinkedIn profile quickly.

I've tried inspecting the link from LinkedIn profile, when I click "plus icon" on my "Education "section.

Here's how the link looks like:

`https://www.linkedin.com/in/{username}/add-edit/EDUCATION/?profileFormEntryPoint=PROFILE_SECTION&trackingId={numbers_and_letters}&desktopBackground=MAIN_PROFILE&lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_profile_view_base%3BmNF9kivERVuSqF86ytflAw%3D%3D`

The form is totally different from licenses and certifications link, it has no `add?startTask` parameter.